# C# XML Deserializing Error: Namespace prefix 'xsd' is not defined

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xml-namespaces

I am trying to deserialize an XML element that I received from a SOAP response, but I am getting the "Namespace prefix 'xsd' is not defined" error. What's the possible solution for this?

Here's the sample response XML I'm getting:

```
<ns0:response xmlns:ns0="http://sample.site.com">
                <ns0:additionalData>
                    <ns0:entry>
                        <ns0:key xsi:type="xsd:string">Test Key</ns0:key>
                        <ns0:value xsi:type="xsd:string">1</ns0:value>
                    </ns0:entry>
                    <ns0:entry>
                        <ns0:key xsi:type="xsd:string">Test Code</ns0:key>
                        <ns0:value xsi:type="xsd:string">1</ns0:value>
                    </ns0:entry>
                </ns0:additionalData>
                <ns0:mpiData>
                    <ns1:authenticationResponse xmlns:ns1="http://sample.site2.com">Y</ns1:authenticationResponse>
                </ns0:mpiData>
            </ns0:response>
```

I'm deserializing it this way:

```
XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Parse(responseText);

var responseElement = xDocument.Descendants().Where(a => a.Name.LocalName == response.ElementName).Select(a => a).Last();

            TResponse response = default(TResponse);

            Stream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

            responseElement.Save(memoryStream);
            memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TResponse));

            using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(memoryStream))
            {
                response = (TResponse)serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
            }

            return response;
```

Comment: Does it work any better if you call `CreateReader` on the `XElement` to get an `XmlReader` and get rid of the intermediate messing about with streams? It does appear to be a fragment with undeclared prefixes.

Comment: Hi, @Damien_The_Unbeliever. When I use that, I'm getting the Base64 data type error. One of the properties of my object has that data type that's why CreateReader is not working for that specific object.

Comment: Then it's highly likely that if/when you get past this issue you're creating by only serializing the fragment without necessary namespaces you'll get right back to that same base64 error. Fix that problem.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? You state the error says the `xsd` prefix is missing, but from the sample it looks like the `xsi` prefix is missing. It also seems, as @Damien_The_Unbeliever suggests, the actual issue relates to this 'base64' data, but this cannot be reproduced from your sample XML and code.

Answer (score 1):

I think the XML is missing this line

xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance

Comment: Hi! Yes, it is declared on the parent node. However, I only need the specific xml element to deserialize. I edited the above description for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the `xsd` namespace prefix by adding

```
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
```

at or above the element on which it's used.

For example, add it to the `ns0:response` element, which is common to all likely places it will be needed:

```
<ns0:response xmlns:ns0="http://sample.site.com"
              xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

Comment: Hi! I don't have the control what the XML might look like, but should I just manually add it via string manipulation or XML atrribute (not sure what to use though), I'm new to this.

Comment: You're getting bad XML from some service. Don't try to repair it, get the problem fixed at source. You can't build a good system on top of bad data.